# AJAX keeps on calling the same page's URL instead of the API URL

Tags: php, symfony, jquery-select2

I'm using **Symfony version 3.*** and I am using *tetranz/select2entity-bundle* to have *Select2* to select assets to be assigned to users.

For some reason, AJAX keeps on calling the same page URL when trying to get the JSON output from an API URL.

URL should be:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/asset/api/asset_list

But the URL used is:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/1?field_name=assets

```
/**
 * Lists all asset entities.
 *
 * @Route("/api/asset_list", name="api_asset_list")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function apiAssetListAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $assets = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Asset')->findAll();

    foreach($assets as $asset)
            $itemArray[] = array('id' => $asset->getId(),'text' => $asset->__toString(),);

    return new Response(json_encode($itemArray), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
}



$builder->add('assets', Select2EntityType::class, [
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'remote_route' => 'api_asset_list',
                    'class' => 'AppBundle::Asset',
                    // 'primary_key' => 'id',
                    'text_property' => 'code',
                    'minimum_input_length' => 2,
                    'page_limit' => 10,
                    'allow_clear' => true,
                    'delay' => 250,
                    'cache' => true,
                    'cache_timeout' => 60000, // if 'cache' is true
                    'language' => 'en',
                    'placeholder' => 'Select assigned assets',
                    // 'object_manager' => $objectManager, // inject a custom object / entity manager 
                ]);
```

My Twig Code is as simple as this since I am using the Form Builder of Symfony to do the work for me:

```
 <div class = "modal" id = "assignModal" tabindex="-1" role = "dialog">
    <div class = "modal-dialog" role = "document">
        <div class = "modal-content">
            <div class = "modal-header">
                <h5 class = "modal-title">Assign Assets</h5>
            </div>
            <div class = "modal-body">
                {{form_start(assign_form)}}
                {{form_widget(assign_form)}}
                <input class = "btn btn-block btn-success" type="submit" value="Assign" />
                {{form_end(assign_form)}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also included this template in in my twig:form_themes configuration:

> TetranzSelect2EntityBundle:Form:fields.html.twig

My list of JS Scripts used:

```
<script src="/js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.collection.js"></script>
<script src="/js/popper.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/datatables.js"></script>
<script src="/js/list.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="/js/select2.js"></script>
<script src="/bundles/tetranzselect2entity/js/select2entity.js"></script>
```

I hope you guys can help.

Comment: If your client side code is requesting the wrong URL, why aren't you showing us the client side code?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with ajax code, but what I can say is that 'remote_route' => 'api_asset_list' at the $builder has the correct url.

Comment: Please show us your twig code, and especially the javascript part

Comment: try to use {{ api_asset_list }}

Comment: HamzaNig: I get "Unable to generate a URL for the named route "{{ api_asset_list }}" as such route does not exist." Error.

Comment: McSky: Done as you requested.

Comment: @AkiraHora where is the code you wrote for ajax call..?

Comment: @GabfHann I didn't write it, symfony did the code writing for me. I'm using tetranz/select2entity-bundle which automates this.

Comment: It probably takes the target URL from the form element, and since you did not explicitly specify one for that, it points to the current URL …?

Comment: @CBroe the bundle should have done that for me. The remote_route property at builder specifies what url will it use.